# How can I scrape the comment off a HTML tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, urllib

I am trying to scrape the comment from a particular HTML can but I am running into problems. I have no problem scraping all the text under the tag, but Only the comments. Can someone help me out.

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError

page=urlopen('https://catalog.data.gov/dataset')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

dataset_number=soup.select('div .new-results')
print(dataset_number)
```

I want extract **HTML comment**  from the data returned by the above code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have made some edits, is it clearer now?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have made some edits, is it clearer now?

Comment: You should replace `urlopen('https://catalog.data.gov/dataset')` with hardcoded text so that we can copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment
from urllib.request import urlopen
page=urlopen('https://catalog.data.gov/dataset')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
dataset_number=soup.select('div .new-results')[0]
for com in dataset_number(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    print(com)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I did this with regex handy.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

page=urlopen('https://catalog.data.gov/dataset')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

dataset_number=soup.select('div .new-results')
result = re.findall('<!--(.*)-->', str(dataset_number))
print(result)
```